# Method is called more than once from one ActionEvent

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, actionevent

I'm trying to code a trivia based game with ActionEvent based buttons. I organized each specific event that is connected to JButton instances in a if-else structure and inside each of these structures, a method would be called. One of these methods would increment a variable that holds the number of the answers that are correct (cor) and wrong (inc):

```
public void compare(String sel , String ans)

{

  //if correct
  if(sel.compareToIgnoreCase(ans) == 0)

    {

        q.setText("Correct! 10 points added!");
        score += 10;
        cor++;

    }

    //if incorrect
    else

    {

        q.setText("Incorrect! The correct answer was: " + ans);
       inc++;

    }

}
```

This set of code would be run from this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)

{

  if(e.equals("GUESS"))

  {

     userGuess = entry.getText();
     answer = ans.get(currentQuestionIndex);
     base.remove(entry);
     base.remove(submit);
     submit.setText("OK");
     submit.setActionCommand("OK");
     submit.addActionListener(this);
     base.add(submit);
     compare(userGuess, answer);

  }
```

...

}

However, whenever the compare method is called, the inc and cor value seems to increment by an ambiguous value. For example, if I were to answer one question right, the new value for cor would be 2 instead of 1. When I answer another right, cor would be 5 instead of two. I tried using tracers in my code but so far, I appears that the program detects the actionEvent that runs compare() is being pressed multiple times, and as a result, it runs said code multiple times. How can I fix my code so that these variables can be incremented correctly by 1.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: what is `e` in `e.equals("GUESS")` ? - where is it set? sould you not be looking at the `event`?

Answer (score 0):

```
submit.addActionListener(this);
```

Don't add the ActionListener in the actionPerformed() method.

Each time the actionPerformed is invoked you add another listener, so when you click on the "Submit" button you have code that is executed multiple times.